# how to solve FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1 error?

Tags: android, web-services

I have an app that work very well but some times when I add some class and code to my program my app crashes. In my `logcat` error is for this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
```

and in my code is this:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

for this I can not improve my app.

my logcat:

```
8871-8929/com.example.first E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio.Okio
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:90)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:208)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:389)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:233)
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.6.+'
compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:+'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.4.0'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
}
```

Comment: add your complete logcat error

Comment: what is the version of OKHTTP ?

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp needs Okio, which OkHttp uses for fast I/O and resizable buffers. You can download Okio (latest JAR) [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.okio%7Cokio%7C1.0.0%7Cjar).

or

Android gradle : compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'

Reference from https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/870

Comment: I have compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0' and  compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+' in my gradle

Comment: Okio is required , use this also and your issue will be resolved

Comment: what result comes out after adding okio .

Comment: have same issue. before result comes.

Comment: add your build.gradle with your question

Comment: I posted my build.gradle